# Why is it so that I keep getting the error that Driver sponsor is not defined, even though I placed it within a class?

Tags: python

I have been trying my hand at a NASCAR project, where I would have to use a class to create 20 unique vehicles and then have them race ( or to see who would reach 500 miles first, through the means of repeatedly choosing a different speed between 1 and 120 and adding it to an increasing odometer). I made what you see below and ran it, and it boots well into the Python IDLE. However, it will always tell me that NameError: name 'Driver_sponsor' is not defined. See, I have been facing this error for a while now, and I have tried placing the Driver_sponsor list into a class, placing it into the Main def and placing the keyword self. before it. No matter what I did, I faced this error. I am going to go back into my class book to see what I can do, but I am hoping that someone here can tell me what I am missing within my code, since, really, I am extremely lost.

```
from random import randint
import time 

class Car:
    def __init__(self,Driver_Name,Sponsor):
        self.__Total_Odometer_Miles = 0
        self.__Speed_Miles_Per_Hour = 0
        self.__Driver_Name = Driver_Name
        self.__Sponsor = Sponsor
        self.__Driver = ('Drivers name Missing')
        self.__Sponsor = ('Sponsor Missing')
        self.__Driver_sponsor = {'A.J.Allmendinger:3M','Aric Almirola:Allegiant ','Trevpr Bayne:AMR ','Ryan Blaney:Camping World ','Clint Bowyer:Chevrolet ',
                              'Chris Buesher:Coca-Cola','Kurt Busch:Coca-light ','Kyle Busch:Credit One ','Landon Cassill:Ford','Matt DiBenedetto:FDP',
                              'Austin Dillon:','Ty Dillon:','Dale Earnhardt:Jacob Companies ','Chase Elliott: M & M ','Denny Hamlin: Microsoft ',
                              'Kevin Harvick:GoodYear ','Jimmie Johnson:Nationwide','Erik Jones:SUNOCO','Kasey Kahne:Toyota','Matt Kenseth:Visa ' }
    def Name(self,Driver_Name):
        self.__Driver_Name = Driver_Name
    def Retrieve_Name(self):
        return self.__Driver_Name
    def __mutualize__(self):
        self.__Total_Odometer_Miles = 0
        self.__Speed_Miles_Per_Hour = 0
    def sponsors(self):
        self.__Driver_sponsor = {'A.J.Allmendinger:3M','Aric Almirola:Allegiant ','Trevpr Bayne:AMR ','Ryan Blaney:Camping World ','Clint Bowyer:Chevrolet ',
                              'Chris Buesher:Coca-Cola','Kurt Busch:Coca-light ','Kyle Busch:Credit One ','Landon Cassill:Ford','Matt DiBenedetto:FDP',
                              'Austin Dillon:','Ty Dillon:','Dale Earnhardt:Jacob Companies ','Chase Elliott: M & M ','Denny Hamlin: Microsoft ',
                              'Kevin Harvick:GoodYear ','Jimmie Johnson:Nationwide','Erik Jones:SUNOCO','Kasey Kahne:Toyota','Matt Kenseth:Visa ' }
    def Retrieve_sponsor(self,Driver_sponsor):
         return self.__Driver_sponsor

def main():
    for key in Driver_sponsor():
            CurrentCar = Car()
            CurrentCar.Driver = key
            CurrentCar.Sponsor = val
            CurrentCar.MPH = randint(1,120)
            time.sleep(.05)
            time = 5
            currentCar.ODT = 5
            CurrentCar.ODT = CurrentCar.ODT + CurrentCar.MPH*Time
            print(CurrentCar.Driver,CurrentCar.ODT)
            if CurrentCar.ODT >= 500:
                print('\ the winner is',key,'t\ sponsored by',val)

main()
```

Comment: The name isn't defined. Where do you think should it be defined in your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, you're getting this error because you're calling a variable that isn't set.

But more importantly, you're trying to access the driver-sponsor dict before you've initialized an instance of `Car` (which currently only happens *inside* the loop that iterates over `Driver_sponsor`!).

If you want to loop over driver-sponsor pairs and initialize a new `Car` for each one, then do you really need the full `Driver_sponsor` dict initialized for every `Car`?  If so, just pass it as an argument when constructing `Car` and populate `self.__Driver_sponsor`.

For example:

```
driver_sponsor_pairs = {'A.J.Allmendinger:3M',...,'Matt Kenseth:Visa'}

class Car:
    def __init__(self, driver_sponsor):
        # ...
        self.driver_sponsor = driver_sponsor

CurrentCar = Car(driver_sponsor=driver_sponsor_pairs)

# now refer to CurrentCar.driver_sponsor
```

Second, you are only asking for `key` when looping over the `Driver_sponsor` dict, but you call on both `key` (for `Driver`) and `val` (for `Sponsor`) in each loop .  Extract both `key` and `val` in your loop creation. You'll need the `.items()` dict method to get both values:

```
for key, val in driver_sponsor_pairs.items():
    ...
```

Third, your `Car` `__init__` expects `Driver` and `Sponsor` arguments, but you try to define `CurrentCar = Car()` and then populate `CurrentCar.Driver` and `CurrentCar.Sponsor` afterwards.  Continuing with the above updates, try instead:

```
CurrentCar = Car(Driver=key, Sponsor=val)
```

Fourth, you won't need the `Retrieve_sponsor()` method if you already have the `.Sponsor` attribute set.

There are a lot of misunderstandings here about Object syntax and design.  You may find it frustrating to try and debug at this level of complexity.  I would suggest starting very simply, say, with `Car()` having just one attribute.  Test that, make sure it works as you want, and then build more attributes and methods from there.